# Loading WMS service to display WMS legend when exporting map layout

Tags: pyqgis, wms, legend, layouts

I am using QGIS 3.2.0 and want to use PyQGIS to load WMS services to the layout and output the layout and end up with a PNG image. The problem is with the legend, which is not showing on the map.

Using WMS services
`http://127.0.0.1:8002/geoserver/yqycxt/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities`

The result of loading in the software is as follows

[image]

I load it in this way:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
urlWithParams = "crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=jizhen&url=http://127.0.0.1:8002/geoserver/yqycxt/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&username=username&password=password&contextualWMSLegend=1&styles"
# Used contextualWMSLegend=1
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'test_wms_legend_load', 'wms')
if rlayer.isValid():
    project.addMapLayer(rlayer, addToLegend=True)
```

Referenced:

- [issues_21152](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/21152)
- [How to get legend image from a WMS using PyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273196/how-to-get-legend-image-from-a-wms-using-pyqgis)

But the results do not contain the WMS legend.

Loading WMS in the software, the legend is valid.

[image]